# BCP Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, bcp, ssms-2012

Hi i am running below BCP query to fetch the data

`exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select top 10 ProductFamilyID,ProductSetID,ProductFamilyCode,ProductFamilyName from MPLA.dbo.tblLCFProductFamily" queryout D:\requirement.txt -w -T -S "server_name"'`

i am running this on SSMS 2012 by connecting my localdb. I have access on the server given in the query also but still i am getting below error :

```
SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'FAREAST\D--113062586$'.
NULL
```

The user `FAREAST\D--113062586$` mentioned doesn't even exists for my localdb. How to overcome this ?

Comment: `bcp ... -T` means Trusted connection. I.e. it tries to log in to the SqlServer with the user running the query (i.e. the user running the sql server process). Drop the -T and use `-U username and -P password`

Comment: Actually the server used is having only windows authentication.But still I tried giving username and password and now i am getting error for whatever username i am giving.

Comment: `-T` will always use the current windows user. It will ignore any user and password supplied. In your case, when it's run in `xp_cmdshell`, that is the windows user it runs under. I had the same login error but for a different reason: If the database name you use is incorrect it will give you a logon error, even though it's just an incorrect database name

Comment: `FAREAST\D--113062586$` sounds like a computer-account or local service. Is `FAREAST` the name of the computer or a domain/AD?

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly specifying the Server Name, User Name and Password.

```
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select top 10 ProductFamilyID,ProductSetID,ProductFamilyCode,ProductFamilyName from MPLA.dbo.tblLCFProductFamily" queryout D:\requirement.txt -w -T -S YourServerName -U UserName -P Password'
```